# Java Playfrawork code hot reloading not working with pac4j Library

Tags: java, playframework, pac4j

I have Play framework (v2.8.16) and  Pac4j (Pac4j v10.0.2, pac4j-http:4.5.7 &&  pac4j-oauth:4.5.7, pac4j-jwt:4.5.7) with Java 12 . my application is a Java app and using Play's multi-module setup. In Play's development mode there is a hot code reloading feature that seems to get hickups on custom classes that extend Pac4j types. This happens very frequently  dose not matter running from IDE (IntelliJ) or command line SBT is the same.

I have a class that extends pac4j Profile

`public class CustomJwtProfile extends org.pac4j.jwt.profile.JwtProfile`

On  application  startp everthing is fine but after modifying the code while application running hot reloading of classess fails with this  error

`play.api.PlayException: Execution exception[[ClassCastException: class my.package.CustomJwtProfile cannot be cast to class class my.package.CustomJwtProfile (class my.package.CustomJwtProfile is in unnamed module of loader play.runsupport.DelegatedResourcesClassLoader @2a1321ec; my.package.CustomJwtProfile is in unnamed module of loader play.runsupport.DelegatedResourcesClassLoader @47424930)]]`

not sure why this happening and specifically to  custom classes that extend Pac4j .
is pac4j playing with class loaders ?

full stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class my.package.CustomJwtProfile  cannot be cast to class my.package.CustomJwtProfile  (my.package.CustomJwtProfile  is in unnamed module of l
oader play.runsupport.DelegatedResourcesClassLoader @10d471bd; my.package.CustomJwtProfile  is in unnamed module of loader play.runsupport.DelegatedResourcesClassLoader @3de8b5d4)
        at my.package1.PermissionChecker.check(PermissionChecker.java:20)
        at org.pac4j.core.authorization.authorizer.AbstractRequireAnyAuthorizer.isProfileAuthorized(AbstractRequireAnyAuthorizer.java:21)
        at org.pac4j.core.authorization.authorizer.ProfileAuthorizer.isAnyAuthorized(ProfileAuthorizer.java:41)
        at org.pac4j.core.authorization.authorizer.AbstractRequireElementAuthorizer.isAuthorized(AbstractRequireElementAuthorizer.java:23)
        at org.pac4j.core.authorization.checker.DefaultAuthorizationChecker.isAuthorized(DefaultAuthorizationChecker.java:90)
        at org.pac4j.core.authorization.checker.DefaultAuthorizationChecker.isAuthorized(DefaultAuthorizationChecker.java:72)
        at org.pac4j.core.engine.DefaultSecurityLogic.perform(DefaultSecurityLogic.java:146)
        at org.pac4j.play.java.SecureAction.internalCall(SecureAction.java:95)
        at org.pac4j.play.java.SecureAction.call(SecureAction.java:85)
        at org.pac4j.play.filters.SecurityFilter.proceedRuleLogic(SecurityFilter.scala:102)
```

Actually CustomJwtProfile is package "my.package" and calling class "PermissionChecker.java" in another package "my.package1", basically both class  are in different module

the definition of the "permissionChecker" & CustomJwtProfile class is as following

```
public class PermissionChecker<U extends CustomJwtProfile >

public class CustomJwtProfile extends org.pac4j.jwt.profile.JwtProfile
```

and if i change the PermissionChecker definition to following then no error all good

```
public class PermissionChecker<U extends org.pac4j.jwt.profile.JwtProfile>
```

Answer (score 0):

pac4j does not play much with the classloaders, it uses them sometimes to find a class and its constructor.

I'm surprised by the double "class" word after "cannot be cast to": `class my.package.CustomJwtProfile cannot be cast to class class my.package.CustomJwtProfile`. It feels like the class type is used instead of the class itself.

Can you copy/paste the full stack trace?

Comment: full stack trace added above in original Question, and i guess double "class" word after "cannot be cast to": is a typo, sorry for that

Comment: also added more detail to the Question.

Comment: So this is a problem of JDK modules visibility configuration?

Comment: No Its Playframwork Module, not JDK module

Comment: Does this happen with JDK 11?

Comment: no its jdk 12 , but with 11 its also the same